# Views width fails to change properly with auto-layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have 4 `UIButtons` in a `static cell` with width `constraints` and regular constraints on all 4 sides.

[image]

At a certain point, I want to change the `constraints` width. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.constraintArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.budgetWidthConstraint, self.categorieWidthConstraint, self.extraButtonWidthConstraint, nil];
}

- (void)myLayout
{
    CGFloat cellWidth = self.thirdCell.frame.size.width;

    [self.constraintArray[2] setConstant:cellWidth / 6];
    [self.constraintArray[1] setConstant:cellWidth / 6];
    [self.constraintArray[0] setConstant:cellWidth / 3];
}

- (void)myAction {
    [self myLayout];
}
```

The problem is, when the `simulators` orientation is changed, the `buttons` width doesn't change to the size they should be. I have to call `myAction` again in order for the `buttons` to layout as they should. I tired calling `myLayout` from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self myLayout];
}
```

but that didn't work, and I don't get any errors.

**Update 1:**

`Constraint` widths start like this:

```
constraintArray[1] =  62.500000
constraintArray[2] =  62.500000
constraintArray[3] =  125.000000
```

When rotate device:

```
constraintArray[1] =  62.500000
constraintArray[2] =  62.500000
constraintArray[3] =  80.500000
```

What it should be after rotation: (or after I call `myAction`)

```
constraintArray[1] =  55.083333 
constraintArray[2] =  55.083333 
constraintArray[3] =  110.000000
```

**Update 2:**

Here is a link to a similar project that has the same problem: [Project](http://www.filedropper.com/test2_7)

Comment: Does cellWidth change to what you want? Are you saying `setConstant:` not work? You might need to post `self.constraintArray[2] setConstant:cellWidth / 6]` code. what is inside constraintArray and the method `setConstant` implementation

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Add breakpoints at setConstant, and check if your constraint in the array has changed to what you want. Then use view debugging feature in xcode to see it is the updated constraint.

Comment: And you don't answer if `cellWidth` has changed to what you want. this kind of issues has no short way, we need to follow the chain to find out where is the issue.

Comment: cellWdith does change accordingly.

Comment: alright, if cellWdith changed, how about your 3 contraints? Are they changed? Also, try [self myLayout] in viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` doesn't work. In middle of checking the 3 constraints

Comment: not ads, but I recommend you use view debugging in xcode or use 'reveal' software to debug it. Very effecient to solve auto layout issues. It seems like either it fails to change the constraint, or it is changed back after you change it

Comment: use equal width constraint

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but there will only be 2 out of 3 that are the same width, and it will switch off. For ex. at one point, constraintArray[1] and constraintArray[2] will be equal, but at another point constraintArray[1] and constraintArray[3] will be equal.

Comment: ok....so programatically you want to change the width according to requirements

Comment: yes. and I did. But the problem is when the orientation changes, the widths are weird until I call `myAction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the buttons to resize when their parent view resizes, don't set their width constraints. Instead set their leading and trailing constraints, this will leave their widths to be flexible.

If you need to change their widths programatically, then adjust a leading or trailing constraint.

To get width to be equal proportionally set an "Equal Widths" constraint and set its multiplier (e.g. multiplier=2 means one is double the size of the other).

Then if you need to hide a button, give a Width constraint as well as the Equal Widths constraint but set the Width constraints priority to 1 and set the Equal Width constraint priority to 999. You can hide/show the button programatically by swapping these constraint's priorities

Comment: But all the leading and trailing constraint are always set to 0

Comment: Of the 3 constraints Leading, Trailing and Width, you should only use 2 for each view. The 1 you omit will be the 'flexible' constraint which will change as the parent view changes.

Comment: So I think you just need to delete your width constraints

Comment: If I deleted the width constraints, Xcode gives me a warning.

Comment: And you've set both the leading AND trailing constraints?

Comment: Try deleting the leading & trailing constraints and re-adding them

Comment: Here is a link to a project with a similar problem: http://www.filedropper.com/test2_7 Instead of going back and forth, I figured it'll be easier if you had the project in front of you.

Comment: Ive modified you project, this should be what you need. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159158975/test2.zip

Comment: I had to add an EqualWidths constraint to each of the buttons and for the smaller buttons I had to set multiplier=2

Comment: I hope this isn't a bother, but I now can't toggle between `[self threeSegmentLayout]` and `[self fourSegmentLayout]`

Comment: Ive come this far, might as well ;)  dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159158975/test2.zip is updated and toggles between 3/4 buttons. Ive updated this answer to explain what I did

Answer (score 1):

I just check out your project. I get to know that you have implemented  it wrong way. See constraint works on margin. And here all buttons didn't get proper margin.

Also you have applied equal width to 100 cause problem.
Your second and third view size are same but your fourth view size is different.

To overcome this issue you should take one more button (fifth button) after fourth button.
Now add second and third view inside a view and fourth and fifth inside a view. And assign equal width to the first button, second view and third view.  Now then change orientation it will not cause problem. You should update fourth and fifth button like second and third.